# Subequation reference including all letters

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I would like my reference to a set of subequations to automatically contain all the letters of the relecent subequations. See example code below. I am imagining that this will involve a macro `\labelsubeqn` to replace the labels in the example code, and perhaps take a second input argument indicating the number of subequations present.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations} \label{eqn1}
    \begin{align}
        a&=b    \\
        c&=d
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations} \label{eqn2}
    \begin{align}
        a&=b    \\
        c&=d    \\
        e&=f
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

The reference `\eqref{eqn1}' I would like to appear as `(1a,b)' 
and the reference `\eqref{eqn2}' I would like to appear as `(2a-c)'.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's good, but…

Why not? Because the purpose of the top level `\label` is to refer to the global number and the subequations are there for the reader to see.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook{env/subequations/begin}
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \label \__eddy_subequations_label:n
 }
\AddToHook{env/subequations/end}
 {
  \bool_if:NT \l__eddy_subequations_label_defer_bool
   {
    \__eddy_subequations_label_do:V \l__eddy_subequations_label_tl
   }
 }

\bool_new:N \l__eddy_subequations_label_defer_bool
\tl_new:N \l__eddy_subequations_label_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__eddy_subequations_label:n
 {
  \use:c { @bsphack }
  \bool_set_true:N \l__eddy_subequations_label_defer_bool
  \tl_set:Nn \l__eddy_subequations_label_tl { #1 }
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \label { ltx@label }
  \use:c { @esphack }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__eddy_subequations_label_do:n
 {
  \int_case:nnF { \value{equation} }
   {
    {1}{ \__eddy_subequations_label_aux:nn { #1 } { a } } % just in case
    {2}{ \__eddy_subequations_label_aux:nn { #1 } { a,b } }
   }
   { \__eddy_subequations_label_aux:nn { #1 } { a-\int_to_alph:n { \value{equation} } } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__eddy_subequations_label_do:n { V }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__eddy_subequations_label_aux:nn
 {
  \tl_set:cx { @currentlabel } { \theparentequation #2 }
  \label{#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations} \label{eqn1}
    \begin{align}
        a&=b    \\
        c&=d
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations} \label{eqn2}
    \begin{align}
        a&=b    \\
        c&=d    \\
        e&=f
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

The reference `\eqref{eqn1}' I would like to appear as `(1a,b)' 
and the reference `\eqref{eqn2}' I would like to appear as `(2a-c)'.

\end{document}
```

The idea is that the first `\label` command inside `subequations` is for setting the global reference. However, we need to defer the setting when the full number of subequations is known. So `\label` is redefined to do the job and then it returns to its normal status.

You *need* this first `\label` if you plan to use `\label` also in environments that are not math displays inside the `subequations` environments, such as `enumerate`, for instance.

The deferred job suitably sets `\@currentlabel` and issues `\label`.

Note: this won't set the anchor for `hyperref` at the beginning of the `subequations` environment. That would cost much more.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow! Thats quite an answer. Is it possible to do it more simply using a new macro, rather than redefining label? I can input the number of subequations present manually into the macro, or the letter for it to use.

Comment: @Eddy What's the problem? This will adjust automatically if the number of subequations changes.

Comment: well, i mean, there's no problem as such, its just that I can neither read it nor debug it if it goes wrong! Most of the commands I have never seen before! I'll give it a test and see what happens.

Comment: I _think_ I had written something similar with "normal" macros but I discarded it afterwards since it did not survive the loading of `hyperref`. Have you checked this in such a case?

Comment: I have tested the MWE you provided, and the document does not compile for me, either with or without the inclusion of xparse. The log file is euite extensive, and incledes e.g. 'Undefined control sequence. \AddToHook', 'Undefined control sequence. ...:NT \l__eddy_subequations_label_defer_bool'.

Comment: @Eddy You need an up-to-date TeX distribution. What are you running?

Comment: MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6499 (1.40.18) (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)

Comment: @Eddy Start by doing a full update.

Comment: Really? I installed the most up to date version of MikTex during the last week, and ran the MikTex update this morning. How out of date can my latex compiler be?